# Acess Denied exception while trying to set table clustered in HSQLDB

Tags: java, hsqldb

I have a table Orders with a unique index on it -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Idx_Date_States ON Orders(ReportDate, CustomerState, SellerState);
```

When I try to create a clustered Index on the table, I get an access denied exception even though there is no other connection to the database -

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Access is denied in statement [SET TABLE Orders
 CLUSTERED ON (ReportDate, CustomerState, SellerState)]
         at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
         at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
         at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
         at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your table must be a CACHED table, otherwise this exception is thrown.

If you want uniqueness for the given columns, create either a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE constraint, rather than an index.

An index does not need to be a UNIQUE index to make it clustered.

You can execute the statement for the columns of any index or UNIQUE constraint.